# in machine learning’s impurity measures. Where does the word Gini originate from? Why entropy is represented with an H? Where does this H come from?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

[image: Context]

Where does the word Gini originate from? Why entropy is represented with an H? Where does this H come from?

Comment: From the ancestors of 
 [Corrado Gini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrado_Gini)?

Comment: @kimchilover makes sense! And the H from entropy? :S

Comment: Ask this question on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ .  Obviously $H$ _means_ entropy here, but why the letter $H$ is used is a minor mystery. Bolzmann called it $S$; Shannon seems to have called it $H$ from the beginning but its not, I think, clear why.  At any rate, $H$ is the standard symbol for entropy in information theory, but not in the sciences.